# How do I debug the move_upload_file() function when there's no clear reason for failure?

Tags: php, file-upload

**TL;DR**

How do I go about debugging the `move_upload_file()` function effectively to get to the real cause behind it's valid filename failures?

How do I find out why `move_upload_file` is returning false even if it's working?

**Full Story**

I'm working on a on-click update image function, but `move_upload_file()` is letting the side down.

This is the PHP function responsible for handling uploads:

```
/**
 * upload $file -> $target location
 *
 * @param $file
 * @param $target
 *
 * @return bool
 */
public function upload($file, $target)
{
    return move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], $target. $file['name']);
}
```

But this returns a false boolean value.

This led me to amend my function for debugging purposes:

```
/**
 * upload $file -> $target location
 *
 * @param $file
 * @param $target
 *
 * @return bool
*/
public function upload($file, $target)
{
    ini_set('display_errors',1);
    ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
    error_reporting(-1);

    var_dump($_FILES);
    var_dump($file);
    var_dump($target);
    var_dump($target. $file['name']);
    var_dump($target. $_FILES['icon']['name']);

    var_dump(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['icon']['tmp_name'], $target. $_FILES['icon']['name']));
    var_dump(move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], $target. $file['name']));

    return move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], $target. $file['name']);
}
```

This prints (relative to `var_dump()` location):

```
$_FILES var_dump => 
array(1) {
  ["icon"]=>
  array(5) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(17) "marker_orange.png"
    ["type"]=>
    string(9) "image/png"
    ["tmp_name"]=>
    string(14) "/tmp/php59mLlb"
    ["error"]=>
    int(0)
    ["size"]=>
    int(802)
  }
}

$file var_dump =>
array(5) {
  ["name"]=>
  string(17) "marker_orange.png"
  ["type"]=>
  string(9) "image/png"
  ["tmp_name"]=>
  string(14) "/tmp/php59mLlb"
  ["error"]=>
  int(0)
  ["size"]=>
  int(802)
}

$target var_dump =>
string(81) "/var/www/dev/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/my-plugin/pub/images/dealer-icons/"

$target. $file['name'] var_dump =>
string(98) "/var/www/dev/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/my-plugin/pub/images/dealer-icons/marker_orange.png"

$target. $_FILES['icon']['name'] var_dump =>
string(98) "/var/www/dev/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/my-plugin/pub/images/dealer-icons/marker_orange.png"

move_uploaded_file (using $_FILES) => 
bool(false)

move_upload_file (using passed $file) =>
bool(false)
```

From the `var_dump`'s, it doesn't look like there's anything obvious and no warning/error is shown. [The manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php) says this on the matter:

> Returns TRUE on success.
>
> If filename is not a valid upload file, then no action will occur, and move_uploaded_file() will return FALSE.
>
> If filename is a valid upload file, but cannot be moved for some reason, no action will occur, and move_uploaded_file() will return FALSE. Additionally, a warning will be issued.

This leads me to believe that **file** isn't a valid upload file:

> This function checks to ensure that the file designated by filename is a valid upload file (meaning that it was uploaded via PHP's HTTP POST upload mechanism). If the file is valid, it will be moved to the filename given by destination.

Yet, using `$_FILES` instead of the passed `$file` (idea was to pass a singular `$_FILES['key']` to the function) still returns false without warning.

After reading a few SO posts, I checked my permissions but all seems fine there:

[image: Correct Permissions proof]

Doing: `cd <copy path from var_dump($target)>` takes me to the correct directory - so it exists, is owned by the webserver owner and is on permissions 755.

Then finally, the ajax function responsible for setting the function off:

```
//on dynamic added file input change, upload the file
$(document).on('change', '#edit_photo', function()
{
    let formData = new FormData(document.getElementById('edit_photo_form'));
    formData.append('action', 'update-photo');

    $.ajax({
        data: formData,
        type: 'post',
        url: endpoint, //endpoint = '/full/path/to/Admin.php'
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function(res)
        {
            console.log(res);
            if (res == 0) {
                alert('Error updating profile pic.. fire Trey!')
            }
        },
        error: function(res) {alert('nope');console.log(res)}
    })
});
```

so it's definitely a HTTP POST request:

[image: HTTP POST proof]

Doing `sudo cat /var/log/apache2/error.log` also shows nothing about the request at all.

How do I go about debugging the `move_upload_file()` function effectively to get to the real cause behind it's valid filename failures?

**Edit: a half-working edit**

I edited my JS function and HTML so that the form is included on load, and clicking the image sets the values on existing inputs within the form, which, got the function to work:

```
//onclick image uploader/updater
$('.edit-photo').click(function()
{
    let type = $(this).attr('data-type'),
        id = $(this).attr('data-id'),
        name;

    switch(parseInt(type))
    {
        case 1: name = 'profile_pic'; break;
        case 2: name = 'cover_pic'; break;
        case 3: name = 'icon'; break
    }

    $('#edit-photo').attr('name', name);

    $('#edit-photo-form').append(
        '<input type="hidden" name="type" value="'+ type +'" />' +
        '<input type="hidden" name="id" value="'+ id +'" />'
    );

    $(document).find('#edit-photo').click();
});

$('#edit-photo').change(function()
{
    $('#edit-photo-form').submit()
});


$('#edit-photo-form').submit(function(e)
{
    e.preventDefault();

    let formData = new FormData(this);
    formData.append('action', 'update-photo');

    $.ajax({
        data: formData,
        type: 'post',
        url: endpoint,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function(res)
        {
            console.log(res);
            if (res == 0) {
                alert('Error updating profile pic.. try again. If the problem persists, talk to Trey')
            }
        },
        error: function(res) {ajaxError(res)}
    })
});
```

This actually gets the file uploaded, however, `move_upload_file()` is returning false, yet, I see the image in the target folder, so why is it returning false, I changed my function to this:

```
public function upload($file, $target)
{
    var_dump('file:'. $file['tmp_name']);
    var_dump('target:'. $target. $file['name']);
    var_dump(move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], $target. $file['name']));

    return move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], $target. $file['name']);
}
```

This outputs:

> string(19) "file:/tmp/phpv24QIy"
> string(98) "target:/var/www/dev/wordpress-plugins/wp-content/plugins/my-plugin/pub/images/cover/tttt.jpeg"
> bool(false)

How can it work and return false at the same time?

Comment: Once you're using WordPress, have you tried [wp_upload_bits()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_upload_bits/) method?

Comment: @CaduDeCastroAlves I mean, I'd prefer to use native functionality that should work

Comment: Is the file being uploaded?

Comment: @CaduDeCastroAlves as the question states - no

Comment: Have you tried to change permissions to 777 to see if it works?

Comment: @CaduDeCastroAlves 777 is never the solution - even if it worked, I'd not accept that as an answer - as this function works for other uploads

Comment: I see, but if it works, you will know that it might be related to directory permissions.

Comment: @CaduDeCastroAlves but then how would you explain it working for the other function uses?

Comment: And I've suggest wp_upload_bits() because it should handle all strange behavior WordPress would have, including file and directory permissions.

Comment: @CaduDeCastroAlves I'm happy to trial, but I'd like to get to the root of this, as it doesn't make sense how it can fail in this specific case-usage :/

Comment: "but then how would you explain it working for the other function uses?"
This is definitely weird...